# How to put the tuple (i,j) in a list multiple times without using concatenation?

Tags: python, list

I want to add some tuples `(i,j)` in a list as many time as they occur in another function. My result right now is `[[(0, 0), (0, 0)]]`, but I want it to be only a single list `[(0, 0), (0, 0)]`. Is there any way I can do this without using libraries?

```
list= [[(i,j)]*number_occurences]
print(list)
>>> [[(0, 0), (0, 0)]]
```

Comment: Drop the outer brackets.

Comment: and don't use `list` as a variable...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: That's no safer. You still repeated the references to `i` and `j` the same number of times, just in different (immutable) `tuple`s. `[(i,j)] * number_of_occurences` is *much* faster, equally safe, and avoids making a whole bunch of unnecessarily shallow copied tuples. Now, if it was `[[i,j]] * number_of_occurences`, that's a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: What does concatenation have to do with this?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: It has to do with avoiding a problem that can occur when using ways that don't use concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You literally wrote the `[[` that you don't want. So, simply don't do that! Write just the one `[` instead.

For example:

```
>>> [(1,2)]*5
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Happy to be corrected but that's a direct copy/paste from my terminal.

Comment: That was a really stupid question indeed. However i messed up because your 5 was a function in my code. The problem was there was another fault in that function. It's fixed though. Thank you for taking your time, even for stupid questions like this. :)